# Does not receive bitcoin into bitcoind daemon

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

I have installed bitcoind daemon into server and create address for individual users. An User A sends 0.0004 BTC into my Bitcoind daemon server, yet it will not appears into my server. I have checked using the following commands:

```
bitcoin-cli getbalance
```

Following [Link](https://www.blockchain.com/ko/btc/address/16PLFqBVrJ1qjeTgnX6ivna3FbeYyuX5bd) will generate acknowledgement from user transaction.It will show transaction history, yet it will not receive coin into my bitcoind daemon server. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: i set 8332 port and already set up rpcuser and rpcpass.

Answer (score -1):

Your node is not synced with the block chain. Examine the output of

```
bitcoin-cli getblockcount
```

Compare this number with the number of the block that includes your transaction. It will be lower. You will have to wait for the node to catch up with the block chain, or possibly resolve any network connection issues that are preventing it from doing that.

(As an aside, note that you don't need to use real bitcoin for testing. There is [testnet](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#testnet) for that.)

Comment: bitcoin-cli getblockcount

The number is the same. I still can not recognize it.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Thank you for your kindly reply.

Comment: What is the number reported by getblockcount?

Comment: 565,263 blockcount

Comment: What is the output of `bitcoin-cli getreceivedbyaddress 16PLFqBVrJ1qjeTgnX6ivna3FbeYyuX5bd`  ?

Comment: output? How can i decide on it?
I just installed bitcoind.

Comment: hobbang2580@ubuntu-s-6vcpu-16gb-nyc1-01:~$ bitcoin-cli getreceivedbyaddress 16PLFqBVrJ1qjeTgnX6ivna3FbeYyuX5bd
error code: -4
error message:
Address not found in wallet

Comment: Well, that answers your question. The balance is zero because the address that received the bitcoins is not in your wallet.